# My JavaScript function is not working - Trying to compare two functions and return a statement within the 2nd function

Tags: javascript

Hey StackOverflow community!

I'm new here and just started learning JS via Odin Project. I'm on my first JS project (rock, paper, scissors app) and am stuck....

I'll summarize what my intentions are below followed by my code.

//The user would input a value of either rock, paper, or scissors

//With the user value, it would be compared to the value of the computer's selection at random

//Depending on that comparison from both the user's input and the computer generated one, a return statement would be given

Have tried almost everything and not sure how to move forward! Please help.

```
    function computerPlay() {
        let gameOptions = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
        const gameChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameOptions.length);

        console.log(gameChoice, gameOptions[gameChoice]);
    }

    

    
    function playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection){

        
        
        if(playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
            return console.log('You lose! Paper beats rock.');
        }else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            return console.log('You lose! Scissors beats paper.');
        }else if(playerSelection === 'scissors' &&  computerSelection === 'rock') {
            return console.log('You lose! Rock beats scissors');
        }else if(playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
            return console.log('Its a draw!');
        }else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
            return console.log('Its a draw!');
        }else if(playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            return console.log('Its a draw!');
        }else if(playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
            return console.log('You win!')
        }else if(playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            return console.log('You win!')
        }else {
            return console.log('You win!')
        }
        
    }
    
    
        const playerSelection = prompt('Choose either rock, paper, or scissors', '');
        const computerSelection = computerPlay();

        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

I was hoping the conditional statement within the 2nd function would be able to accomplish this. Still trying to wrap my head around functions, parameters, and arguments.

Any and all help would be GREATLY appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: Step one is probably returning `gameChoice` from `computerPlay()`. As it is the assignment does nothing, so you're calling `playRound` with `undefined` as the second parameter in all cases.

Comment: You were right! I didn't return anything thus no value. Thank you for your help man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`computerPlay()` does not return any value. So `computerSelection` will be undefined.

Also, change this line `console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));` to just `playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);` and remove the `return` statements from `playRound()`.

Also, your logic can be greatly simplified. For example, `if (playerSelection === computerSelection) console.log("It's a draw");`

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help. I thought computerPlay() is returning a random value from the array of gameOption?

haha thanks for the simplification tip, consider me complete newb at JS!

Answer (score 0):

computerPlay function does not return any value. I think you should console each value before do playRound

Comment: I thought it is returning the value from gameOptions array? hmmm. Anyways, thanks for your help man.

Comment: You were right man, I had to return them first to get the value. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.